# A large planet composed of all natural elements is created. What happens?

Tags: science-based, planets

In my story, I am playing around with the idea of a planet being primordially created by gods. This planet consists of [nearly all of the natural elements in the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table#Overview), and in equal amounts.

Let us assume that the mass of this planet is just under the minimum required mass to undergo [thermonuclear fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermonuclear_fusion) and be considered [a star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_dwarf). This planet would be a [sub-brown dwarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-brown_dwarf).

Let's say the official mass is **12 [Jupiter masses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_mass)**, or:
$$ \left( 1.89813 \times 10^{27} \, \mathrm{kg} \right) \times 12$$
This is equal to $ 2.27776 \times 10^{28} \, \mathrm{kg}$.

---

For the purpose of this question "natural elements" will refer to the stable elements, or those of atomic numbers 1-83, skipping 43 and 61. [Bismuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bismuth), although discovered to be weakly radioactive, will be considered stable for this question because it has a half-life of more than a billion times the estimated age of the universe.

This leaves us with 81 elements for the scope of this question:


[<sup><sub>$$
    \begin{matrix}
    \mathrm{Hydrogen} & \mathrm{Helium} & \mathrm{Lithium} & \mathrm{Beryllium} & \mathrm{Boron} & \mathrm{Carbon} & \mathrm{Nitrogen} & \mathrm{Oxygen} & \mathrm{Fluorine} \\
\mathrm{Neon} & \mathrm{Sodium} & \mathrm{Magnesium} & \mathrm{Aluminum} & \mathrm{Silicon} & \mathrm{Phosphorus} & \mathrm{Sulfer} & \mathrm{Chlorine}  & \mathrm{Argon} \\
\mathrm{Potassium} & \mathrm{Calcium} & \mathrm{Scandium} & \mathrm{Titanium} & \mathrm{Vanadium} & \mathrm{Chromium} & \mathrm{Manganese} & \mathrm{Iron} & \mathrm{Cobalt} \\
\mathrm{Nickel} & \mathrm{Copper} & \mathrm{Zinc} & \mathrm{Gallium} & \mathrm{Germanium} & \mathrm{Arsenic} & \mathrm{Selenium} & \mathrm{Bromine} & \mathrm{Krypton} \\
\mathrm{Rubidum} & \mathrm{Strontium} & \mathrm{Yttrium} & \mathrm{Zirconium} & \mathrm{Niobium} & \mathrm{Molybdenum} & \mathrm{Ruthenium} & \mathrm{Rhodium} & \mathrm{Palladium} \\
\mathrm{Silver} & \mathrm{Cadmium} & \mathrm{Indium} & \mathrm{Tin} & \mathrm{Antimony} & \mathrm{Tellurium} & \mathrm{Iodine} & \mathrm{Xenon} & \mathrm{Caesium} \\
\mathrm{Barium} & \mathrm{Lathanum} & \mathrm{Cerium} & \mathrm{Praseodymium} & \mathrm{Neodymium} & \mathrm{Samarium} & \mathrm{Europium} & \mathrm{Gadolinium} & \mathrm{Terbium} \\
\mathrm{Dysprosium} & \mathrm{Holmium} & \mathrm{Erbium} & \mathrm{Thulium} & \mathrm{Ytterbium} & \mathrm{Lutetium} & \mathrm{Hafnium} & \mathrm{Tantalum} & \mathrm{Tungsten} \\
\mathrm{Rhenium} & \mathrm{Osmium} & \mathrm{Iridium} & \mathrm{Platinum} & \mathrm{Gold} & \mathrm{Mercury} & \mathrm{Thallium} & \mathrm{Lead} & \mathrm{Bismuth}
    \end{matrix}
$$</sub></sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table#Overview)

---

Each element takes up an equal portion of the mass, which means that each element in the planet has a total mass of $ \frac{2.27776 \times 10^{28} \, \mathrm{kg}}{81} = 2.812049 \times 10^{26}  \, \mathrm{kg}$.

Let us assume that the elements are uniformly distributed throughout the entire planet. For every cubic centimeter, each element is present and in roughly equal quantities of mass as the other elements.

If it is important for this question, then let's use the lightest and most stable isotopes for each element. For example, in the case of [Hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen), please use <sup>1</sup>H or [protium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_hydrogen). For [Helium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium), please use <sup>3</sup>He or [Helium-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_helium), despite the fact the <sup>4</sup>He is a million times more abundant in the universe. For this question, go with the lightest of the stable isotopes.

Let us also assume that the planet is far enough away from other objects so that there are no outstanding perturbations that would destabilize the planet's orbit or affect the way the elements arrange themselves. There is a minimum amount of received energy, enough to prevent complications from near-absolute zero temperatures. By this I mean that it can be in orbit around a star or other system, but the way it is gravitationally effected should be minimal.

Let's also say that its rotational period is about 24 hours, like that of the Earth.

## What happens in this situation?

What happens immediately after this mass forms? What happens over a million years? Over a billion years?

I know that heavier elements like gold and lead will settle towards the center of the planet, while lighter elements like hydrogen and helium will end up closer to the surface. What I'd like to know is the time frames for this situation, and what the end, stable result would look like. Are there any interesting stages involving chemical reactions?

Everything happening following the initial creation of the planet should follow the known laws of physics in a [science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based) manner.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100845/discussion-on-question-by-overlord-reinstate-monica-a-large-planet-composed-of).

Answer (score 2):

**Very Bad Things**

None of the nuclear elements are present, so that's a good thing. But all the Halogens and Alkali metals are present. And those will react on pretty much everything around them, especially the higher elements. The good news is that there will be less of the more reactive halogens and alkalis by count (since they're heavier and we're equalizing by weight) but that's 9 out of 81 elements that right off the bat are going to start giving you problems by reacting with a overheating everything around them, as the reactions are, of course, highly exergonic. My knowledge of chemistry isn't sufficient to tell me what kind of reactions will occur, but I don't think anyone has actually replicated this in practice.

Next of course are the alkalines and chalcogens. Not as reactive as, of course, but we're talking elements like oxygen, sulfur, magnesium - all nice reactive elements. Another 9 reactive elements, which, like the previous reactions, will undergo exergonic reactions. This will more or less superheat *everything.* The reactants from both sets of reactive elements will be gases that work their way to the surfaces. I say gases, because even though the reactants won't necessarily be gases at normal Earth tempatures, this planet will have anything but that. (I don't know what they will be, because 81-element jumble chemistry hasn't been explored, but they'll probably be lighter than the metals.)

Now, with three exceptions (carbon, nitrogen, phosphate) everything else is a metal or a metalloid which has been superheated to probably thousands of degrees Farenheit. And these are less reactive than the other 18 previously discussed elements, so while a good amount of them will form reactants will the highly-reactive elements, the rest of them will be fused together from the high heat. And they might stay separate if they were separate from the beginning, but they weren't, so they're not.

The end result is a planet made from an alloy of all the metals and metalloids on the table, basically the mother of all tainted alloys. The atmosphere is going to be horrible - the heat will cook it into a vicious storm of chemicals and everything in the air is horribly reactive. That's what happens immediately. The planet is basically death to anything that's near it, but thankfully it's not near anything. There's also the possibility that chain reactions of these highly reactive elements leads to hundred mile high flares of reactions venting this stuff clean into space. There's not enough oxygen to sustain a worldwide firestorm, which is probably a good thing.

Given time, thanks to the high heat, it's likely that the heavier elements will make their way to the core, forming an internal core of the heavier elements, with a crust made from the latter ones. I imagine the crust of the planet will be mainly composed of alloys, given that the crust will cool first (eventually), meaning that the surface will have the least purity of everything. The lighter and more reactive elements will be trapped in the atmosphere, meaning that even once the planet settles, this planet will be a hellscape of some of the scariest substances in chemistry, and quite possibly home to hundreds that we don't know about.

**Disclaimer**: This is an opinion by someone who knows a lot of chemistry but has no way of knowing whether I took into account everything that needs to be taken into account. This is a vague guess on my part, and at the very least, I'm hoping this is a good account of at least part of the many events.

Comment: What does “good thing” and “bad thing” even mean when there’s no life? Black holes are good things, and so are yellow dwarf fusion stars. Because no one has to live there. It’s a mess of chemical reactions with no cultural or moral or even scientific impact on any world (because it isn’t near any world)

Comment: I have tendency to view chemistry from an organic standpoint, so I kind of wince whenever I see reactions that would kill a human. I just put it there to give an idea of what was going to happen i.e. it's nothing going to be an idealistic  picnic. Anyone human on the planet would be quite dead. (Though I'd be curious as to what chemicals can be grabbed from the atmosphere.)

Comment: That would have been a more valid question. “What atmospheric compounds might a traveler find above this world?” But “What would happen if _____” is the definition of an unanswerable question.

Comment: @Vogon Poet Funny how that unanswerable question seems to have a pretty good answer to it right now.

Comment: This is actually kind of what I was looking for, but I also wanted timescales.

Answer (score 0):

They won't stay uniformely distributed. The internal heat will melt those deep into the planet, they will sink, and in their process of sinking, will heat more rocks resulting in a runaway meltdown, like the Earth's Iron Catastrophe, with most siderophile elements and the heavyest ones, locked in the nucleus. Luckly you excluded uranium from your composition, because the extra amount of uranium in the core would risk the planet becoming a nuclear reactor.

Comment: Doesn't Lack of a "nuclear reactor" means that the planet will cool down pretty fast. I am not sure if that is "lucky"

Comment: It takes billions of years for just the contraction heat of an ice giant to leak away -- even Uranus, which seems to lack a nuclear heat source internally, still radiates more heat than it receives from the sun (though less so than Neptune and the larger gas giants).